# remove bottom whitespace from iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, whitespace

I have a menu that changes the src location of an iframe when a selection is clicked. There is a small bit of white space at the top (under the top bar) and bottom of the page that I can't seem to get rid of.

[image: this is the whitespaces above and below the iframe that I am referring to]

I have read other answers here and tried changing the div around the iframe to `display:flex;`, which fixed the issue momentarily until I edited the menu a bit, which made the white spaces return again. I couldn't find any other answers on stackoverflow that have worked. There is no open paragraph tag causing the issue, like some other answers suggested. I also tried changing/adding `display:block;` to the iframe to no avail.

Here is the div and enclosed iframe HTML:

```
<div class="frameBox">
   <iframe src="example.html" frameborder="0" id="frame"></iframe>      
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the frameBox class:

```
.frameBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 8vh);
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 7vh;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
}
.frameBox iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 8vh);
    top: 0vh;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause of that whitespace is you set the framebox `top: 7vh;` and it's `position: fixed;`

I used iframe before and i hope this could will help you.

1. Change `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;`
2. Change the height of your .frameBox from `height: calc(100vh - 8vh);` to `height: 100%;`
3. The content of your iframe should be `width: 100%;` only.
4. Remove this `z-index: 1;`(It seems that you don't needed it)
5. Adding `top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;` will stretch the i frame and leaving no whitespace.

Here's how:

```css
.frameBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
}
.frameBox iframe{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frameBox">
    <iframe src="example.html" frameborder="0" id="frame"></iframe>      
  </div>
```